# TensorFlow 2.0: Training with zero padded labels

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training on a dataset with labels of varying length. I have zero padded all of these labels to be of equal length so training can be conducted. This leaves ~33% of the dataset targets with the value of 0.

However, training results in the model simply outputting zero. I've added a masking layer before and after my output layer with mask_value=0. This has helped although there are still a large amount of zero values showing up when using model.predict() on validation data.

My hope is for the model to effectively only focus on updating based on non-zero labels and not base any training on these zero-padded values.

Am I using the masking layer correctly? The only examples I can see for it is when being used with timeseries data for RNN/LSTM downstreaming. Furthermore, how does the masking layer affect back-propagation on the outputs?

Is there a better way to handle zero padded labels? How should I go about this? Many thanks.

Comment: What does you labels represent?

Comment: @maciek97x 3d components per node on a graph. The graphs are varying sizes, thus differing number of nodes, thus different sized targets

Comment: You could define a custom loss that takes only into account the non zero labels. The masking layer is usually used for variable length *input* sequences (with RNNs).

Comment: Each value in your output corresponds to one node?

Comment: @AndrzejO three output values per node

Comment: You could – based on some intermediate layer – add additional layer(s), which would output for each node one value V(node) ∈[0,1]. This would be a prediction whether this node exists. Then for each node, multiply each of the current three output values with V(node); that will be the new output. Very easily the network will learn that V(node) should be either very close to 0 or very close to 1. This way your current network can focus on predicting values without bothering to set the values to zero for non-existing nodes